# Nginx use fallback upstream server if default server is not reachable

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, proxy

I am currently working on a Nginx config to group some of my docker containers into subdomains. Some of these containers are not running permanently and prevent nginx from starting (with error `host not found in upstream "somecontainer:5000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:48`) because the host defined in the upstream is not reachable. Is there a way to set a fallback upstream server in case the first one is not running?

The config currently looks like that:

```
upstream somecontainer {
    server somecontainer:5000;
    # here i need something like: if host is unreachable
    # server fallbackserver:5000
}

server {
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     server_name some.subdomain.com;
     root /public_html/;

     client_max_body_size 16384m;

     ssl on;
     server_tokens off;
     ssl_certificate sslstuff;
     ssl_certificate_key sslstuff;

     ssl_buffer_size 8k;
     ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

     location / {
        proxy_pass        http://somecontainer;
        proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;  
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fallback for an nginx upstream proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380439/fallback-for-an-nginx-upstream-proxy)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Even with a second server, i get nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "somecontainer:5000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:48 - which is totally understandable if the container isn't running

Comment: This question does not seem programming-related. It might be better suited for [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's because of Nginx design.

You can use variable in `proxy_pass` which will be resolved at runtime, so there is no such error on nginx load:

```
        set $destination_host somecontainer;
        proxy_pass http://$destination_host:5000;
```

But the disadvantage of the solution above is that you can not leverage nginx `upstream` such as specify load balancing algorithm or weighted balancing...

Additionally, You have to patch nginx if both upstream and dynamic service initialization is a need. I have a patch which change that Nginx design and was discussed here and I'm using it on production environment for a while. You can check it if patching is not a problem to you https://github.com/ZigzagAK/ngx_dynamic_upstream/issues/8#issuecomment-814702336

Comment: when we use variable to specify hostname, i believe we also need to specify the `resolver`? were you able to get this working without resolver ?

Comment: Yes, `resolver` is required